# Html Pattern to validate ISBN bot 10 and 13 digit (regular expression)

Tags: regex, html, validation, input, isbn

hey am new so i dont have any idea how to validate isbn in html input type=""text"
for both 13 and 10 digit isbn pls help me ...

> Blockquote

```
<input type="text" id="name" name="name" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-5" pattren="??" />
```

Comment: <input type="text" id="name" name="name" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-5" pattren="??" />

Comment: `pattren` that is a typo; it's misspelled.

Answer (score 0):

You probably can't do this with regex alone since the last digit is a calculated checksum, but [here's a good resource](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/regular-expressions-cookbook/9781449327453/ch04s13.html) to get you headed in the right direction and invalidate some obvious cases. There's information on how the checksum is calculated there and also on Wikipedia.

**ISBN-10 example regex**:

```
^(?:ISBN(?:-10)?:?\)?(?=[0-9X]{10}$|(?=(?:[0-9]+[-\]){3})[-\0-9X]{13}$)[0-9]{1,5}[-\]?[0-9]+[-\]?[0-9]+[-\]?[0-9X]$
```

**ISBN-13 example regex**:

```
^(?:ISBN(?:-13)?:?\)?(?=[0-9]{13}$|(?=(?:[0-9]+[-\]){4})[-\0-9]{17}$)97[89][-\]?[0-9]{1,5}[-\]?[0-9]+[-\]?[0-9]+[-\]?[0-9]$
```

Comment: thanks for your answer

Comment: No problem... hope it helped solve the issue!

Comment: @AdiKing the answer should be accepted in order to mark your question as solved; you haven't done that.